# Can you declare a member variable with decltype on an object function?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

```
struct Example
{
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens;
    decltype (tokens.begin()) i;
};
```

On Visual Studio 2013 I'm getting a compiler error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union.

Is this valid C++11 code, if not, is there a way to do this without typing the long templated type for the iterator?

My logic for thinking decltype should work is that the compiler can absolutely see the function signature, so I thought you could declare a variable based on its return type.

Comment: [Clang++ and g++ accept similar code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0489c0804f555dc)

Comment: You can, that code should work fine (and does in G++ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e40b5dfc294c7601)

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's probably Microsoft's Visual Studio just being slow to have full C++11 compliance.

Comment: @Jonathan: I can't think of any feature relevant to this code that MSVC is lacking in.

Comment: Confirmed that Visual Studio behaves as posted: http://rextester.com/VZOW90472

Comment: Possibly [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797682/c-decltype-of-class-member-access-incompletely-implemented)

Comment: Fascinating: http://rextester.com/HKVD57274 when the code is moved to main, the error changes to `error C2653: 'boost' : is not a class or namespace name`, which kind of invalidates my prior tests sortof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is valid. This is a [known VS bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797682/c-decltype-of-class-member-access-incompletely-implemented). The example in the linked bug report is similar:

```
#include <list>

struct used {
    int bar;
};
struct wrap {
    used u;
    auto foo() -> decltype( u.bar ) { return u.bar; }   // works
    decltype( u.bar ) x;                                // error C2228
    std::list< decltype( u.bar ) > items;               // error C2228
};
```